# Filepicker to point to Assets folder in App

Tags: windows-8.1

I'm using a file picker to read PDF files from the asset folder of the app itself.I have been successful in fetching the files from my systems local drives, Pictures library and desktop but am not able to give the SuggestedStartLocation of the file picker to point to asset folder of the App,since all my files will be placed in the asset folder only and not on the system.Is there anything i can do to make the picker point to Asset folder.It's a Windows 8.1 app ...
Thanks